# Liquibase and Hibernate ddl-auto=update with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase-hibernate

I am integrating liquibase in Spring boot project. I am planning to let hibernate run DB schema changes and run remaining DML queries via liquibase.

- Is it good practice to manage DB changes via both Liquibase and
  Hibernate at the same time ?
- Are there any cons using the same?

Answer (score 0):

Why not running everything from liquibase script? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup

Comment: Hey I can do so. But it will be double effort to write entity class and on other hand its equivalent query. Just wanted to know if it is good practise to do so.

Comment: Theoretically, if hibernate ddl auto update worked in development, it should work in production as well. Yet in reality, it's not always the case. Plus liquibase provides hash with every schema update to double check automatically.

Comment: It's really sad that we have to write these things twice, ad @KapishMalik mentioned.  I would love to see better productivity there.